# Removing specific item from np.array when it matches location

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For a Python program "Particle in a Box", I need to insert a gap in the x,y-plane. I keep track of the x- and y-location of each particle and the x- and y-components of the velocities in numpy arrays.

I have two errors.

1) `positie_y[z] <= 0 and positie_x[z] > 0.8 and positie_x[z] < 0.9` cannot be used for numpy arrays. I am new to numpy arrays, so please explain how to use any() or all() or other options?

2) The `np.delete` is not working: the particles are not disappearing. Is this because I am not using it the right way or is there another way to do it?

```
def particles(n, gap):
    dt = 0.01

    position_x = []
    position_y = []
    speed_x = []
    speed_y = []

    for i in range(n):
        alpha = random.random() * 360
        speed = (0.1)*random.random() * alpha
        speed_x.append(math.sin(snelheid))
        speed_y.append(math.cos(snelheid))
        position_x.append(0.25)
        position_y.append(0.75)
    position_x = np.array(position_x)
    position_y = np.array(position_y)
    speed_x = np.array(speed_x)
    speed_y = np.array(speed_y)
```

Until here, it is working fine. The problem is somewhere in the following code.

```
    while True:
        position_x = position_x + speed_x * dt
        position_y = position_y + speed_y * dt
        # 'z' is the position number of the particle in the numpy array.        
        for z in range(0, n):
            # Gap == 1 means there is a gap.
            if gap == 1:
                # The gap is at y = 0 and 0.8 < x < 0.9
                if position_y[z] <= 0 and position_x[z] > 0.8 and position_x[z] < 0.9:
                    np.delete(position_x, position_x[z])
                    np.delete(position_y, position_y[z])
                    np.delete(speed_x, speed_x[z])
                    np.delete(speed_y, speed_y[z])
```

After that, I will plot each particle with `plt.plot(positie_x, positie_y, 'ro')` and `particles(100, 1)`

Comment: Please post your complete code that shows where gap was defined

Answer (score 0):

The snippet:

```
np.delete(position_x, position_x[z])
```

isn't working because the function numpy.delete doesn't make changes on the given array object, but rather returns a new array without the deleted elements.

So your code should be written like this:

```
position_x = np.delete(position_x, position_x[z])
```